# Getting Error $routeProvider not defined when i try to use ngRoute

Tags: angularjs, routes

this is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow because so far I was able to find all the answers that I needed. This time, I couldn't though. My problem is every time I try to use `ngRoute` I get an error in the console **saying "Error**:

> [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module demoApp due to:
>   $routeProvider.$ is undefined".

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
    <title>AngularJS</title>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src='/home/martin4o29/Documents/WebSites/angular practice/first steps/Controller.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<article>
    <div ng-view>

    </div>
</article>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my Angular code:

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);

demoApp.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.customers = [
        {firstName: 'Fostata', lastName: 'Boklik'},
        {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Hoe'},
        {firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe'}
    ];

    $scope.addCustomer = function(){
        $scope.customers.push({firstName: $scope.newCustFirstName, lastName: $scope.newCustLastName});
    };
}]);

demoApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .$.when('/', {
                templateURL: '/home/martin4o29/Documents/WebSites/angular practice/first steps/Partials/View1.html',
                controller: 'Ctrl'
            })
            .$.when('.view2', {
                templateURL: '/home/martin4o29/Documents/WebSites/angular practice/first steps/Partials/view2.html',
                controller: 'Ctrl'
            })          
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });

    });
```

View1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AngularJS</title>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src='/home/martin4o29/Documents/WebSites/angular practice/first steps/Controller.js'></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app='demoApp'>

    <article data-ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model='name'>
        <br>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter: name"> {{cust.firstName + " " + cust.lastName }}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>  

        <input type="text" data-ng-model='newCustFirstName'>
        <br>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model='newCustLastName'>
        <br>

        <button data-ng-click="addCustomer()">AddCustomer</button>

    </article>

    <a href="#/view2">View2</a>

</body>
</html>
```

view2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AngularJS</title>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='/home/martin4o29/Documents/WebSites/angular practice/first steps/Controller.js'></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app='demoApp'>

    <article data-ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model='name'>
        <br>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter: name"> {{cust.firstName + " " + cust.lastName }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  

    </article>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you get rid of first / in tempURL and see if it works?

Comment: I did it, it's still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all fix your templates

- remove head scripts
- remote ng-app
- remove controller

Example view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <article>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model='name'>
            <br>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter: name"> {{cust.firstName + " " + cust.lastName }}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

Views are defining only the part which should be changed, not the whole app.

Replace `$routeProvider.$.when` with `$routeProvider.when`

Comment: what r u reasons to remove those tags?

Comment: When you load index.html, application is being bootstrapped and from this time, you can start changing parts of it using router. Every route changes part of app, loads template, compiles it and so on. That what you are going to do is to bootstrap the same app within working one. Secondly you have defined controller for your fragment `controller:Ctrl` and you suppose to add it twice with ng-controller directive.

Comment: I got rid of the app, scripts and controllers in my view but it still cant load my demoApp module, still saying that $routeProvider is undefined, I'm just following the angularjs tutorial and im doing everything exactly the same as explained but it's not working for some reason...

Comment: not `$routeProvider.$.when` but `$routeProvider.when`

Comment: That worked, im not getting that error anymore, dumbass sublime angular js package.... lol but now my main html page is not loading any of my views, im just getting a blank page :(